# Similar text categorization problems (word vectors, sentence vectors)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, word-embedding

Purpose: There are a number of statements that need to be organized & clustered (similar keywords organized together).

My knowledge of technology: Learned Python and Tensorflow related content in the last three weeks. Learned some basics.

1. First read the csv file

```py
keywords = pd.read_csv("copy.csv")
cover_words = []
for row in keywords.Keyword:
    cover_words.append(row)
```

2. Tokenizer & Sequences

```py
# Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 10000, oov_token='<OOV>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(cover_words)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
# Sequences
Sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(cover_words)
sentences_padded = pad_sequences(Sequences, padding='post', truncating='post')
```

3. Word Embedding

```py
embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(20000, 4)
tf_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(sentences_padded, tf.float32, name='t')
result = embedding_layer(tf_data)
```

The next idea I had was to use loops to add up the word vectors of sentences to get the "sentence vectors". Then use the loop to find the cosine similarity of the vectors, the closer the similarity, the closer that goes together.

But now I have a problem, because the sentence lengths are not the same, so I use `sentences_padded = pad_sequences(Sequences, padding='post', truncating='post')`  to make all the sentences the same length. So if I need to add up the word vectors of the sentences to get the sentence vectors, is that putting too many invalid vectors into it?

I don't know how to get rid of this invalid vector either. Also I don't know if the above is correct or if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use averaging of embeddings instead of summing them.